Django store variable betrween user requests
Short version:
How do one store a variable in memory in django and make it shareable between different users ?
Long story:
I've written some api using django, and django-ninja
This api uses third party library that helps me to connect to telegram account (library is called Pyrogram)
This library uses some variable and somehow connects to telegram:
I use it like this:
async with Client(session_name, config['api_id'], config['api_hash']) as app:
         DO something

So I want to store this app variable in memory and share between all users.
(I need this because otherwise pyrogram creates another session on user requests and there are limited number of pyrogram sessions)

This is why they creates a database.

You could add it to settings.py and other modules can import it from there.

Sound more like you want have an extra service to handle this. Where "service" should be seen more like a generic term which includes all kind of data storage.

@JohnGordon I can't add to settings because pyrogram don't work well in sync mode, and if i add it in async mode it will give an error that i try to call async function from sync environment

You could leverage Django's caching layer to store it which would be fast and accessible across session. Keep it mind that it will expire though so you may want a backend to save if that is required such as a database,, external file or a secret manager depending on your deployment
